# Using specific list values

Tags: c#, list

Basically after creating the list "rValues" I use the list to see if any value contained within it, `is == 0`. The line being referred to is commented with "line of concern", however this leads, say when upperB is set too 5, to the program writing down the value of x for every value in the list that `is ==0`.

My question is, is there any way of saying that for the first value in the list that `is == 0` it writes down the value of x and then the program continue, almost as if once just a single value of the list is found it is noted and rest of list is deleted? Thank you.

```
     List<int> rValues = new List<int>(); 

            do
            {
                x++;
                v = 0;
                rValues.Clear();
                do
                {
                    v++;
                    r = x % v;
                    rValues.Add(r);
                } while (v < x);

                foreach (int B in rValues)
                {
                    if (B == 0) // line of concern
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(x);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }   
                }

            }
            while (x != upperB);
            Console.ReadLine();

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, do you want to delete all values except the one which is equal to 0? If so, just break the loop when you find the value == 0. Btw, that else statment is redundant.

Comment: If you remove else in foreach loop then I am sure loop will continue.

Comment: I want to write down the value of x when a value in the list == 0 and then delete the entire list including the value equal to 0. However what is currently happening is it writes down the value x for every value in the list which is == 0. So when v is 1 and x is 2 it does 2%1 which is 0 and write the value x down but instead of stopping there and starting again with x = 3 it does 2%2 which is also 0 and writes 2 down again, if that makes sense?
Also just realized v should start at 1 not 0 as everything is divisible by 1 and so every value would be = to 0.

Comment: So let me understand, the moment you get `B==0` you want to print x and delete the whole list. Correct?

Comment: Yes, before any other values of B==0 are found and value of x is printed again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wrote all other loops in the code. To answer the question, that require only like below and also "continue;" is not required.

```
int c=0;
foreach (int B in rValues)
                {
c++;
                    if (B == 0) // line of concern
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(x);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //continue;
rValues.deleteat(c);
                    }   
                }
```

Comment: I put that in and it didn't allow for ".deleteat(c);" without it the problem is still occurring though.

Comment: I tried .removeat(c); instead of .deleteat(c); and the problem is still recurring

Answer (score 0):

Try using linq instead of the foreach loop. And then simply call `rValues.Clear()`

The code should then look like:

```
List<int> rValues = new List<int>(); 

do
{
    x++;
    v = 0;
    rValues.Clear();
    do
    {
        v++;
        r = x % v;
        rValues.Add(r);
    } while (v < x);

//my LINQ expression
    Var B = rValues.FirstOrDefault( (result) => result==0);
    rValues.Clear();

//back to your code
    while (x != upperB);
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, to break out of the loops, the reason that RemoveAt() is not working is that it's a Foreach loop and you cannot modify the Enumerable while you are iterating through it.  It's a safety thing.

```
List<int> rValues = new List<int>();
bool found = false;
    do
    {
        x++;
        int v = 0;
        rValues.Clear();
        do
        {
            v++;
            int r = x % v;
            rValues.Add(r);
        } while (v < x);

        foreach (int B in rValues)
        {
            if (B == 0) // line of concern
            {
                found = true; 
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    while (x != upperB && !found);

    Console.ReadLine();
```